# Считается ли хорошей практикой использовать несколько PRIMARY KEY в одной таблице

Tags: mysql, sql

Считается ли хорошей практикой использовать несколько PRIMARY KEY в одной таблице?

Допустим :

```
create table ConsPravo ( 
 id_ int (100)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
position varchar(2500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
question varchar(2500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (position) 
PRIMARY KEY (question) 
PRIMARY KEY (id_) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;
```

Comment: `PRIMARY KEY` может быть только один, может вы хотели `PRIMARY KEY (id, position, question)` ? А смысл, если у вас есть id, который по сути им и является. Нужны дополнительные индексы - так и создавайте их отдельно, а в PK их совать не надо

Comment: BOPOH я хочу провести связь между колонками двух таблиц, но она не проводится потому что нету  PRIMARY KEY.   Я использую - FOREIGN KEY (id_author) REFERENCES ConsPravo (position) . Или  в position - добавить индекс?

Comment: так сделайте одно уникальное поле(к примеру ваш ID_) и сделайте в других таблицах поле-foreght-key на данное поле. Или ID_ не уникально?

Comment: Сделайте UNIQUE INDEX. Связь устанавливается на любой уникальный ключ/индекс. Это может быть PRIMARY KEY или UNIQUE INDEX

Comment: UNIQUE INDEX `index_api` (`position`) USING BTREE  -так нормально будет работать с  FOREIGN KEY (id_author) REFERENCES ConsPravo (position) ?

Comment: @banme, InnoDB создаст PK в любом случае, поэтому лучше самому указывать его, тем более - здесь id уже есть

Comment: Только зачем делать связь по такому огромному полю (2500)? Вам конечно видней, но здесь явно что-то не так

Comment: banme Это я так, там на самом деле будет стандартное число 255.

Comment: Правильно связь сделать по id, как ворон говорит.

Comment: А для чего она вообще нужна эта связь FOREIGN KEY? Я просто думаю может в других ячейках не делать связь. Просто те данные которые будут размещаться в position и question, будут и в другой таблице.

Comment: Вообще ID в таблице для того и есть, что бы ссылаться на него, а не на какие либо еще данные в таблице. А foreign обеспечивает что в подчиненной таблице в поле могут быть только такие данные, которые есть в основной таблице

Comment: Mike я  с этой целью и делаю связь - цитата Mike: foreign обеспечивает что в подчиненной таблице в поле могут быть только такие данные, которые есть в основной таблице.    ||||||  Просто думаю, может не стоить делать связь, мне же придется делать индексы для каждого столбца.

Comment: FOREIGN KEY, ссылаясь на ключевое поле в главной таблице (PRIMARY KEY или UNIQUE KEY), ссылается на всю запись. По ключу автоматом вытягиваются как за ниточку и все остальные поля. Не надо каждое поле индексировать без надобности. Однако остальные поля можно проиндексировать для увеличения скорости выборки, когда в запросе используются условия по этим полям.

Comment: banme - Но без индексации я не могу установить связь с другими столбцами у которых нету PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: Вот из сервера , который писали  - профи вроде бы.  Хочу заметить что тут два PRIMARY KEY   :     CREATE TABLE `character_friends` (
  `charId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `friendId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `friend_name` varchar(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`charId`,`friend_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: Да ты не понял. Здесь один primary key, но из нескольких полей (из 2х). Primary key в принципе не может быть больше одного. И здесь используется составной PK, потому что это таблица связи двух других. Как самостоятельная сущность не используется в принципе. В этом случае вполне разумно использовать составной ключ, компоненты которого ссылаются на соответствующие главные таблицы. Посмотри может там есть пара foreign key?

Comment: banme - Посмотри может там есть пара foreign key?  - Пока его не наблюдаю. Похоже что они вообще писали без foreign key.

Comment: Со слепу не разглядел. Тут хитрость составного ключа в чём-то другом. Может что бы обеспечить уникальность friend_name в пределах одного charId, но чтобы разные charId могли иметь друзей тезок. На фига это в primary key запихали не понятно. Может не такие уж они и профессионалы.

Comment: @semiromid Вотпрос. А зачем в другой таблице хранить какой либо текст, повторяющий собой текст в основной таблице. такие связи предполагают, что в подчиненной таблице несколько записей с таким содержимым. Если это так, то при изменении содержимого хотя бы на одну букву его надо будет менять сразу во всех записях, а при наличии FOREING сделает вообще невозможным, т.к. сначала надо будет _добавить_ запись с таким содержимым в головную таблицу, поменять подчиненную и удалить старую запись из головной. ссылка только по ID как раз обеспечивает, что текст надо менять только в головной таблице

Comment: banme -тоже не понятно, хоть поднимай сервер и просматривай.

Comment: banme - У других - тоже судя по всему профи  :   CREATE TABLE `character_friends` (
  `char_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `friend_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`char_id`,`friend_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: @semiromid Ну вот эта таблица из двух полей - явная таблица связи других таблиц и сделана абсолютно правильно. дополнительные поля ID записи тут не нужны. Примари обеспечивает уникальность связи чар-френд

Comment: Правильно должно быть так: CREATE TABLE frends (id int primary key, char_id int foreign key references chars(id), frens_name varchar)  и create unique index on frends (char_id, frend_name)

Comment: @banme Вы не правы. тут таблица связывает чара и френда, сами френды явно вынесены в отдельную таблицу и имеют свою ID. что позволяет одного и того же френда иметь двум и более чарам. Френды - это то же сущности простого хранения имени явно недостаточно

Comment: @Mike Ну да. И такое возможно. Только не только лишь разные чары могут иметь одного друга, но и один и тот же чар может иметь одного и того же друга хоть 100500 раз, но под разными именами?

Comment: Таким образом получается таблица псевдонимов, на которой решили не делать суррогатный pk, а взяли естественный в данной ситуации. Чтобы по-быстренькому и совместить приятное с полезным.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33087/discussion-on-question-by-semiromid-----).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нет, несколько первичных ключей *не является* нормальной практикой. Основное назначение первичного ключа уникально идентифицировать сущность описываемую данной таблицей.

Первичный ключ должен быть таким, что бы за время жизни записи по возможности не меняться никогда. В некоторых случаях можно найти у сущности некий признак подходящий на роль первичного ключа. Например, двухбуквенные коды стран (`RU`), эти коды стандартизированы, применяются одинаково во всем мире, меняются только при геополитических изменениях, т.е. ключ меняется тогда, когда меняется сама сущность. При создании справочника стран такое поле можно делать первичным ключом. В случаях, когда, подходящего по свойствам признака нет - делают просто числовой ID.

Длинные текстовые поля очень плохие первичные ключи, потому, что в них легко могут быть банальные опечатки. И попытка исправить такую опечатку приведет к необходимости поменять это поле не только в этой таблице, но и во всех таблицах, ссылающихся на данную. А таких записей могут быть миллионы ... Кроме того, сама политика `FOREIGN KEY` не позволит просто так изменить первичный ключ, если на него есть ссылки. База не может допустить что бы в подчиненных таблицах существовали записи со значениями ссылающихся полей отсутствующих в головной таблице. Следовательно перед изменением первичного ключа необходимо во всех подчиненных таблицах заранее поправить ссылки на новый ключ, но новый ключ в этот момент уже должен существовать в головной таблице. Единственным способом такого изменения, не нарушающего ссылки, является создание новой записи с новым значением ключа, правке всех ссылок и удалении записи со старым значением ключа.

Создание ссылок на разные поля одной записи так же *не является* нормальной практикой. Нет смысла ссылаться на одну и ту же сущность разными способами, гораздо проще во всей базе ссылаться на данную сущность одинаково. Значения остальных полей данной сущности всегда можно узнать по ее единственному первичному ключу.

Comment: Справедливости ради надо заметить, что можно указать правило, как поступать в случае изменения/удаления ключа: CASCADE - каскадное изменение/удаление подчинённых записей, NO ACTION - ничего не делать, SET TO NULL - установить в null

Comment: @banme Да, я хотел как то выделить это, но предложением "просто так не позволит" не получилось. Просто on cascade update встречается крайне редко у СУБД, а setnull и delete для изменения ключа явно не подходит. У Oracle в принципе можно объявить констраинт как отложенный и тогда его проверка будет происходить при commit всей транзакции, так что можно спокойно заапдейтить по очереди, а потом дать commit. Но в общем то это частные случаи

Comment: Может наоборот очень редко не встречается cascade. Это же как-никак стандарт, как и пр. опции. Удалил пользователя и каскадом его друзей. Не фиг больше здесь делать. И ключ менять не всегда надо. При удалении какой-нибудь позиции из справочника. Да хоть тех стран. Пусть страна происхождения будет неизвестна. NULL вполне себе разрешенное значение для foreign key. Это редко используется только потому, что эти ситуации стало модным обрабатывать в приложениях. Куда не ткни везде такая есть такая функция. А что она ещё и в базе всегда была - люди уже забывают.

Comment: @banme Вы меня не поняли. Я сказал что именно автоматическое _изменение_ встречается редко. А не удаление и SetNULL. Просто если я хочу поменять ключ, то setnull меня не устроит, т.к. в подчиненной таблице могут быть другие записи с NULL и я потом их просто не отличу, что бы поправить. У меня же речь шла исключительно о модификации "неправильных" ключей.

Comment: То есть, и это то что делали профи тоже не является нормой? Хочу заметить что тут почему то хоть  PRIMARY KEY, но значение в `charId`,`friend_name`, могут повторяться. Если один человек добавит например двух друзей.    CREATE TABLE `character_friends` (
  `charId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `friendId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `friend_name` varchar(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`charId`,`friend_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: @semiromid Я бы этих "профи" ... По такой таблице получается, что у конкретного charId может быть только один друг с именем "Петя" и никакой другой Петя добавится в друзья уже не сможет. По хорошему эта таблица должна быть разбита на 2. В одной именно те, кто могут быть друзьями (т.е. в ней 2 поля friend_id primary и friend_name вообще не в индексах) и таблица друзей чаров в том виде как вы ее в коментах к вопросу представляли, из 2х полей char_id, friend_id. Она позволит связывать чаров с любыми друзьями и любая такая связь будет уникальной, т.к. там оба поля в  primary.

Comment: Mike - ЦИТАТА Mike: (По такой таблице получается, что у конкретного charId может быть только один друг с именем "Петя" и никакой другой Петя добавится в друзья уже не сможет.)  ОТВЕТ -Я тоже так думал. Два часа назад или сколько там, я поднял по быстренькому сервер, и добавил себе 2-х друзей. Оказывается что они очень хорошо добавляются. Сейчас еще не успел проверить что там происходит, почему это работает. В процессе понимания.

Comment: Mike - Они хитро сделали. Я понял! Там все отлично работает. Главное что бы (charId и friend_name)  одновременно не совпадали. Потому что мы не можем добавить того друга, который уже у нас записан.

Comment: @semiromid Да, оно конечно так. Но разве у _одного_ чара не может быть двух друзей с одинаковыми _именами_ ? Что, если реально второй Петя захочет дружить с тем же charId ? Если второй Петя решит дружить с тем же chaId им потребуется внести _вторую_ запись с точно такими же полями, а этого они сделать не смогут. Либо им придется придусывать другой charId, что как я подозреваю так же не верно, если чар один и тот же

Comment: Mike  - ЦИТАТА Mike: (Но разве у одного чара не может быть двух друзей с одинаковыми именами ?  ОТВЕТ: В данном построении таблицы,  у одного чара не могут быть два друга с одинаковыми именами. Но тут и на сервере их создать нельзя, два чара с одинаковыми именами.  если (Петя --добавил в друзья -->Аню), (Петя2 --добавил в друзья -->Аню) Почему Петя2 смог добавить Аню? Потому что эта запись в таблице уникальна. Так как у нас расширенный PRIMARY KEY, то и сравниваться сразу будут 2-а значения на уникальность.

Comment: @semiromid Ну если они изначально уникальны - то ok. Правда не понимаю зачем хранить еще и friend_id и имя. Получается что они одну и ту же связку friend_id-friend_name хранят по несколько раз. И не дай бог им захотеть фичу с возможностью поменять имя своему чару, им придется это имя в куче записей менять. Это просто не оптимально, конечно скорость получения имен друзей ускоряет ...

Comment: Mike - имя хранят для отображения его в списке друзей, когда этот список друзей раскрываешь в игре. Если бы там не только имя отображалось а еще и аватарка , то хранили бы еще и ссылку на аватарку или саму аватарку. Для того что бы не искать данные в двух таблицах.  Хотя другая команда делала только две колонки, без имени. Ну тогда они должны были искать имя в другой таблице. То есть, задействовали две таблицы вместо одной.

Comment: @semiromid Я понимаю. Да, вариант рабочий, но это _не красиво_. Это называется "избыточность информации", особенно если бы были еще аватарки. во первых места больше занимает, во вторых, как и писал в ответе - править не удобно. Я бы лучше, как изначально писал, хранил бы тут только id, а все остальное запросом бы отлично получал. были бы _серьезные_ проблемы в скорости, возможно подумал бы о таком дублировании информации. Просто такие решения - потенциальные грабли.

Comment: Mike - Да, править совсем не удобно будет. Почему они так сделали, я не знаю. Править действительно не удобно. Если поменять допустим имя персонажу, то как я только что проверил имя в таблице друзей не меняется. Зачем они это тогда сделали..хм

Comment: @semiromid Из разумных объяснений - хотели ускорить выборку, хотя я тут выигрыша особо не вижу. Может быть где нибудь есть отдельный скрипт который синхронизирует данные, например. Или должен быть триггер, но его забыли. Скрипт мне кажется вероятным, ибо грабли обычно лечатся костылями :)

Answer (score -1):

Наугад.

```
create table ConsPravo ( 
 id_ int (100)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,7
position varchar(2500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
question varchar(2500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
unique (position,question), 
PRIMARY KEY (id_) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;
```